# Theorem 1.7.9 of Megginson: Completeness is a three-space property.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, proof-explanation

This is a theorem from *Megginson's An Introduction to Banach Space Theory*. I'll  cut right to the chase:

> All that needs to be checked is that $X$
>   is complete if both $M$ and $X/M$ are. (and by $X/M$ the quotient space is meant.)

Here's the proof:

> Suppose that $M$ and $X/M$ are Banach spaces. Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy
>   sequence in $X$. Since $\lVert (x_n- X_m) +M \rVert  \leq  \lVert x_n- x_m \rVert $ whenever $m,n \in N$,
>   the sequence $( X_n + M)$ is Cauchy in $X/ M$ and so converges to some $y + M$.
>   By Proposition 1.7.6 (b), there is for each positive integer $n$ some $y_n$ in $X$
>   such that $y_n +M = (x_n- y) +M$ and $\lVert y_n \rVert < \lVert (x_n -y) +M \rVert + 2^{-n}$. Then
>   $\lim_n y_n = 0$, so $(x_n- y_n- y)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $M$ and therefore has
>   a limit $z$ in $M$. It follows that $X_n = (x_n- y_n- y) + y_n + y \rightarrow z + y$ as
>   $n \rightarrow \infty$, so $X$ is complete. $\quad \square$

Question 1: Why $\lim_n y_n = 0$? Perhaps because $\sum_n \lVert y_n \rVert < \infty$ for some secret reason?

Question 2: Why is $(x_n- y_n- y)$ a Cauchy sequence in $M$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Since $x_{n}+M\rightarrow y+M$, then for large $n$, $\|x_{n}-y+M\|<\epsilon$, and we can pick also that $2^{-n}<\epsilon$, then $\|y_{n}\|<2\epsilon$ for all such $n$.

2) $\|(x_{n}-y_{n}-y)-(x_{m}-y_{m}-y)\|\leq\|x_{n}-x_{m}\|+\|y_{n}-y_{m}\|\rightarrow 0$ as $n,m\rightarrow\infty$ because it has been noted that both $\{x_{n}\}$ and $\{y_{n}\}$ are Cauchy.

Comment: Thanks. Reading back the question, I find some typing errors with capital and small letters, but you saw through the question anyway. However my point about the second question was, why does the sequence lie in $M$?

Comment: Because $y_{n}+M=(x_{n}-y)+M$, then $(x_{n}-y_{n})-y\in M$.

Comment: And one thing, the $M$ is particularly a vector subspace. So with $y_{n}+M=(x_{n}-y)+M$, then $y_{n}+a=x_{n}-y+b$ for some $a,b\in M$, then $x_{n}-y-y_{n}=a-b\in M$, once again the last element-set inclusion follows from that $M$ being a vector subspace.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your time :)